# Возведение в степень(x**n)%m

Tags: python

Возведение в степень
По трем натуральным числам x, n и m вычислить значение xn mod m.

Входные данные
Три натуральных числа x, n, m (1 ≤ x, m ≤ 109, 2 ≤ n ≤ 107).

Выходные данные
Вывести xn mod m.

Я сделал вот так:

```
x,n,m = map(int, input().split())

answer = (x**n)%m

print(answer)
```

Но не принимает, один тест не проходит, а результаты теста нельзя увидеть, что бы исправить ошибку. ПОмогите, плиз.

Пример:
Вход:  2 3 100
Выход: 8

Comment: Я всё записал как и ты и у меня всё норм. Ты "2 3 8" вводил при input?
[картинка с примером](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAmXd.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У всем известной функции [pow(base, exp, mod)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) есть малоизвестный третий параметр, который как раз и предназначен для того, чтобы возвращать остаток от деления: `base ** exp % mod`.

Попробуйте воспользоваться этой функцией:

```
answer = pow(x, n, m)
```